# How to restore legacy data during re-create a database by sql server data tools?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

i try to restore the aged data automatically while i re-create the database with the "publish" function of the database project in visual studio 2010.
Does anyone know which preference i have to choose for this function??

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to restore data when publishing a "New" database. You need to build a script that will populate all of the necessary objects or otherwise transfer the data back in to the database.

Red-Gate's SQL Data Compare could be useful for this task or you can find a way to generate scripts that you can call later.

If you just want to update the schema, I'd check your publish settings to make sure you're not choosing the option to "Always Recreate Database".